# PHP display and hide data with php jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have products table:

- `id` int
- `name` varchar(100)

When I choose an option I would like to display the corresponding content. For example:

```
<select class="form-control" name="name" required= "required" id="name">
    <option>Product1</option>
    <option>Product2</option>
    <option>Product3</option>
    <option>Product4</option>
</select>
<div id="content1">content1</div>
<div id="content2">content2</div>
<div id="content3">content3</div>
<div id="content4">content4</div>
```

Display `content1` when `product1` chosen.

Display `content2` when `product2` chosen.

And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code with jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#name').change(function(){
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#content'+$(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="name" required= "required" id="name">
  <option value="1">Product1</option>
  <option value="2">Product2</option>
  <option value="3">Product3</option>
  <option value="4">Product4</option>
</select>
<div id ="content1" class="content">content1</div>
<div id ="content2" class="content">content2</div>
<div id ="content3" class="content">content3</div>
<div id ="content4" class="content">content4</div>
```

Please keep note that the product value should be matched with id value of content div. Like product with value 1 will matched with content div with id content1, so on

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into using a data binding framework like Angular to do this with a fair amount of ease.

Here is a link to a solution which addresses the problem you are trying to solve.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 0):

you can done it by different different scenario..via ajax or simply via jquery/javascript

**via jquery/javascript**

```
<select class="form-control" name="name" required= "required" id="name">
   <option value=''>select product</option>
   <option value='1'>Product1</option>
   <option value='2'>Product2</option>
   <option value='3'>Product3</option>
   <option value='4'>Product4</option>
</select>
<div id ="content1" class="content">content1</div>
<div id ="content2" class="content">content2</div>
<div id ="content3" class="content">content3</div>
<div id ="content4" class="content">content4</div>
<script>
 $('#name').change(function(){
   var value=$(this).val();
   $('.content').hide()
   $('#content'+value).show();
 });
</script>
<style>
.content{display:none;}
</style>
```